# How to render opengl 3.3 into an SDL2 Texture?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, sdl-2, opengl-3

I have been making 2D games with SDL2 for a while now and I decided recently to do 3D games using opengl 3.3 .

Since I have much c++ code made with pure SDL2 that I could reuse in that engine, I wondered, how could I manage to make opengl render to an `SDL_Texture` ?

The idea is to do stuff in 3D with opengl, put it into an `SDL_Texture`, and then do stuff in 2D and render it with SDL2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render to a FBO, use a PBO to pull the pixels back to main memory, then upload the pixels to a `SDL_Texture`.

That's not exactly a "fast path" though, you're probably better off doing everything with OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful, since SDL 2 doesn't yet have explicit support for this.  You can easily trample the GL state that SDL has set up and relies upon in order to render properly.

However, SDL_gpu (full disclosure: I'm the author) does have support for mixing 2D and 3D, though you'd have to port the rest of your SDL_Renderer code.

Comment: As you mentioned, SDL2 is not meant to mix 2D and 3D yet, so as a conclusion the cleanest options, seems, as mentioned : Do all the rendering with opengl or SDL_gpu (ps1 : I'll validate genpfault answer, as the FBO/PBO option, even if slow, solve the problem without code rewritting) (ps2 : SDL_gpu is and impressive rendering alternative, many thanks for sharing it ! )